# I recieve a CORS policy error only when the api throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, axios, cors

This request works but if submit a request that throws an error (with an email that doesn't exist in the system), I receive a CORS policy error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-website.azurewebsites.net/Assign/ByEmail?clientEmail=bademailaddress%40gmail.com&managerEmail=some_mnger%40gmail.com' from origin 'http://localhost:6420' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is an Asp.Net Core Web API solution. It only exhibits this behavior when deployed to its Azure environment, not when run as localhost.

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using wld.admin.api;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var allowAnyOriginsPolicyName = "_allowAnyOriginsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(corsOptions =>
{
    corsOptions.AddPolicy(name: allowAnyOriginsPolicyName,
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});


// Adds Microsoft Identity platform (Azure AD B2C) support to protect this Api
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        },
options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(allowAnyOriginsPolicyName);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxxxx_api");

app.Run();
```

Client code

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="callAssign" onclick="apiGet('Assign/ByEmail', {clientEmail:'bademailaddress@gmail.com', managerEmail:'some_mnger@gmail.com@sendmailtest.com'})">Assign By Email</button>
```

JS

```
  async function apiExec(type, endPoint, params, data)
  {

    var serverAndEndPoint = apiConfig.webApi + endPoint;
    logMessageTime(serverAndEndPoint);
    if(params != null)
    logMessageTime('parameters: ' + JSON.stringify(params));

    getTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {
    
                try {
                  const headers = { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`} }

                    
                    // axios.get(serverAndEndPoint,headers)
                  axios({
                      method: type,
                      url: serverAndEndPoint,
                      headers : {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`},
                      params : params,
                      data : data
                  })                    
                  .then(response2 => {
                    console.log(response2);
                    console.log(response2.data);
                    logMessageTime(JSON.stringify(response2.data));
                    return response2.data;  
                  }, reject => {
                    console.log("reject");
                    console.log(reject);
                  })
                  .catch(error)         
                  {
                    console.log("error caught in apiExec promise");
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                  //callApi(apiConfig.webApi + methodAndParameters, response.accessToken);
                } catch (error) 
                {
                  console.log("error caught in apiExec");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller Code

```
namespace my.api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RequiredScope("tasks.read")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AssignController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AssignController> _logger;

        private string _connectionString = "";
        private IConfiguration _configuration = null;

        public AssignController(ILogger<AssignController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("xxxxx_api");
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ByEmail")]
        public bool ByEmail(string clientEmail, string managerEmail)
        {
            new ManagerOps(_logger, _configuration).AssignToClientByEmail(clientEmail, managerEmail);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include complete code that is configuring request pipeline? All calls that use `IApplicationBuilder` to add middleware like `app.UseCors()` or `app.UseRouting()`. The order of adding those does matter.

Comment: I posted the full Program.cs file. I don't have an example solution I can post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some error handling code in there, even if that means having a try, catch statement that returns false. My assumption is that when the controller is encountering some sort of error, the proper headers arent being included in the response.